# C++ copy constructor taking wrong values

Tags: c++, parameters, constructor, copy

I'm trying to resize my array into a larger one, but when I try to do that I call the copy constructor for my class. It provides wrong values for the passed parameters for some reason. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Copy
    // Copy constructor for class Array
    IntSet::IntSet(const IntSet &init) {
        cout << "IN COPY CONSTRUCTOR FOR: " << init << endl;
        size = init.size;
        count = init.count;

        arr = new bool[size];


        for (int i  = 0; i < size; i++) {
            arr[i] = init.arr[i];
        }
    }
bool IntSet::insert(int value) {
    if(check(value)) {
        cout << "START OF INSERT:       " << *this << "    VALUE: " << value << endl;
        if(value >= size) {
            cout << "INSIDE IF      " << endl;
            size = value + 1;

            IntSet(*this);  
        }

        cout << "AFTER VALUE >= SIZE        " << *this << endl;
        arr[value] = true;
        count++;
        cout << "         AFTER ADDING:      " << *this << " COUNT: " << count << endl;

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have wrote debugging prints throughout the code and here is a snippet.

```
A = {}
Enter ints for set A:  
9
START OF INSERT:       {}    VALUE: 9
INSIDE IF      
IN COPY CONSTRUCTOR FOR: { 2 4 5 9}
IN DESTRUCTOR!!! FOR { 2 4 5 9}
AFTER VALUE >= SIZE        { 2 4 5 9}
               AFTER ADDING:      { 2 4 5 9} COUNT: 1
2
START OF INSERT:       { 2 4 5 9}    VALUE: 2
AFTER VALUE >= SIZE        { 2 4 5 9}
               AFTER ADDING:      { 2 4 5 9} COUNT: 2
1
START OF INSERT:       { 2 4 5 9}    VALUE: 1
AFTER VALUE >= SIZE        { 2 4 5 9}
               AFTER ADDING:      { 1 2 4 5 9} COUNT: 3
-1
A = { 1 2 4 5 9}
IN DESTRUCTOR!!! FOR {}
IN DESTRUCTOR!!! FOR { 1 2 4 5 9}
```

EDIT: To explain a bit what this program does, it is a program that is trying to store ints in  arrays of bools.

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with http://sscce.org/

Comment: I don't see how your comment adds anything. Thanks, though!

Comment: You could start by removing *everything* from your sample that isn't necessary to show the problem. By doing that, you might even find the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`IntSet(*this);`

This line does not do what you want it to do.  What it's doing is creating a temporary IntSet, which is is then immediately destroyed.  You cannot use the copy constructor like this to change the current object represented by `this`.  You'll need to change the fields manually.  Or, as an alternative, look up the copy and swap idiom.

Comment: Already tried: I did this

`bool *temp  = new bool[size];        
            for (int i  = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if(arr[i]) {
                    temp[i] = true;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            arr = temp;
        }`
but doesn't work.